# filling 2d array in java

Tags: java, arrays

Maybe someone can help!

I need to output array which looks:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uafrY.jpg]

But I have:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOYt5.jpg]

What I need to change in script? I do not need a full script, just some basic ideas, how I could improve this!

```
a = 1;
for (i=0; i<=9; i++)

    for (j=9-i; j>=6-i; j--) 
        if (j>=0) {
            A[i][j] = a; a=a+1;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. First off, you can improve your *question* by removing the links, and instead copy/paste the output **text** to the question so that we can read/copy, compare the text you are referring to, very hard to do with images (hence, the downvotes usually). Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the entire source code that you tried to implement to understand your problem better. Nobody will steal your code.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working code which will produce a desired output:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int A[][] = new int[10][10];
        int a = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
            for(int j = 9 - i; j >= 6 - i; j--) {
                if(j >= 0) {
                    A[9-i][j] = a;
                    a = a + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
            StringBuilder printString = new StringBuilder();
            for(int j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
                printString.append(A[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println(printString);
        }
    }
```

Produces output as:

```
34  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
33  32  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
31  30  29  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
28  27  26  25  0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   24  23  22  21  0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   20  19  18  17  0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   16  15  14  13  0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   12  11  10  9   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   8   7   6   5   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   4   3   2   1
```

Comment: Printing them backwards is not the solution to getting the array correct. The question is about getting the array correct, not about printing that exact output.

Comment: @Andreas, the solution is simple then, instead of printing it, just create another array and add those values in it. I dont see there is any point in downvoting the answer.

Comment: I down-voted because the answer is **not useful** for solving the problem of correctly building the *array*. And creating a second array is hardly the right answer, when all you have to do is build it correctly to begin with.

Comment: Okay Mr. Andreas, made changes according to your suggestions :-)

Answer (score 0):

1) When using nested loops I find it helpful to name your loop variables `row` and `col` to make it clear which is which.

2) Either loop forward through both the rows and columns with a decrementing counter (`a`) OR loop backward through the rows and columns with an incrementing counter.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost there, except you have the rows reversed. An easy fix to that is to reverse the row index when assigning the value, i.e. change `A[i][j]` to `A[9-i][j]`.

That will get you the right result, however:

- If you examine the code you'll notice you do `9 - i` in two places, so maybe `i` should be counting backwards.
- You might consider the [advice of Extragorey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40599885/5221149) to name your variables `row` and `col` to clarify their meaning.
- Variables should generally be declared where they are first used. You didn't show your declarations, so I've added them below.
- `a = a + 1` is better written as `a++`, and it can be done inline with the assignment to `A`.
- Since `j` is counting down, the `j>=0` check should just be added to the loop condition.
- You can declare and initialize more than one variable in the for-loop initializer section, as long as they have the same type, which `a` and `i` do.

Here is thus the refined code:

```
int[][] A = new int[10][10];
for (int row = 9, a = 1; row >= 0; row--)
    for (int col = row; col >= row - 3 && col >= 0; col--) 
        A[row][col] = a++;
for (int[] r : A) {
    for (int v : r)
        System.out.printf("%-4d", v);
    System.out.println();
}
```

*Output*

```
34  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
33  32  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
31  30  29  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
28  27  26  25  0   0   0   0   0   0   
0   24  23  22  21  0   0   0   0   0   
0   0   20  19  18  17  0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   16  15  14  13  0   0   0   
0   0   0   0   12  11  10  9   0   0   
0   0   0   0   0   8   7   6   5   0   
0   0   0   0   0   0   4   3   2   1
```